# Intellij IDEA Plugin for RAML

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea, raml

I have just started using RAML in my Java project. I am using Intellij IDEA and there my RAML file is displayed as raw text, without any text highlighting. It seems that it doesn't recognize this type of file at all.

*Is there any plugin for RAML in Intellij IDEA?*

Mostly I tried to google it and also checked in the [list of plugins](http://raml.org/projects/projects#top). If plugin doesn't exist, what would you suggest? It seems that then I would need to use some other tool to modify properly this file.

Comment: It seems there is a plugin which is not doing anything: https://github.com/plducharme/raml-intellij. Currently I edit the file without any plugin.

Comment: Any YAML plug-in will do, that's what I do in Eclipse. But consider using the Atom plug-in, which is fully RAML aware and full of awesome :)

Comment: Could you provide me some link to this plugin? I have tried to search, but found only Atom editor (https://atom.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin [Raml Intellij Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8459?pr=idea) . It is still in beta but you can use it. You can download directly from the Intellij Repositories

Comment: This one is definitely better than only a YAML plugin since it has validation and autocompletion.

Comment: Great! I guess that this is the one that I am looking for, however, for now it was not straight forward how to set it up, was it difficult for you?

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: I installed the plugin and added *.raml file extension to recognized file types, now it seems that there is highlighting, however, I don't see any auto completion, what could be the issue?

Comment: Plugin does not work as of IntelliJ 2021.2.1

Comment: Not compatible with any recent IDEA version since the plugin last was updated in 2017.

Answer (score 9):

RESTful API Modeling Language (RAML) is a YAML-based language for describing RESTful APIs.

Intellij has a plugin for YAML syntax so you can use that for RAML.

- Just go to settings -> Editor -> File Types.
- Then under *Recognized File Types* just scroll down to YAML and select it.
- Now just add *.raml and *.rml to the *Registered Patterns* section and you will get syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have found this way, but unfortunately I have tried only YAML/Ansible plugin which made my raml files highlighted, but in every line I get the error "unexpected toke at the end of the line", however, my raml file is fine and works. Which plugin for YAML are you using?

Comment: I believe it is the built in code style plugin with the default YAML settings. It  doesn't really do a lot in terms of error checking but it indents and gives you different colors for keys, values and comments.

Answer (score 1):

The [RAML Workbench for Atom](http://apiworkbench.com/docs/) is a good way to get started. It provides a lot of guidance to writing RAML.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is a separate editor as I understand, not a plugin for Intellij.

Answer (score 0):

The Raml plugin that I used to mantain is no longer under dev. To replace that I've added raml completion to the DataWeave Plugin. So if you install the [Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10362-mulesoft-dataweave-2-0-and-restsdk-) It will also add Raml and Oas support. Saddly I needed to do this change. All these plugins are being mantain on my spare time